# I need help in understanding ODBC connections between SQL Server and MS Access

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ms-access-2010

I have an Access database with 48 users. The users are allowed into the database via their NT credentials. This is coded into the database via VBA. All of the tables in the database are linked (dns-less) to a single database on a SQL Server.

There are two SQL Server accounts 1 is read only and the other is Read/Write. I am trying to log the users in the read/write table so when I link that table I use the read/write credentials. For all the others I link via the read only credentials.

Here's the problem. If I link the R/W table first then all the other tables are R/W. Same is true in reverse if I link the R/O tables first then the R/W table is read only. Even though when examined via the tbldefs property they have different connection strings it seems the first linked table sets the credentials for all subsequent tables.

I'm convinced at this point I cannot overcome this issue but hoping for a miracle. Other security options are not a possibility i.e. Access login or SQL login

Answer (score 0):

Several methods, but I know of two:

1. Create a simple read-only *view* for each of the R/O tables, then link these, not the source table
2. Attach the R/O tables with pass-through queries. These are R/O in Access.